# Netty: issue with sending message to many servers

Tags: java, networking, netty

I tried to send one message to many servers via netty and just drop server answer. I've prepared a little example with implementation, please look at below:

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainTest {

    private final List<ConnectionInfo> HOSTS = new LinkedList<>();
    private final ByteBuf buf;

    public MainTest() {
        HOSTS.add(new ConnectionInfo("127.0.0.1", 10000));
        HOSTS.add(new ConnectionInfo("127.0.0.1", 20000));
        HOSTS.add(new ConnectionInfo("127.0.0.1", 30000));
        HOSTS.add(new ConnectionInfo("127.0.0.1", 40000));
        HOSTS.add(new ConnectionInfo("127.0.0.1", 50000));

        buf = Unpooled.buffer(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.capacity(); i ++) {
            buf.writeByte((byte) i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
         new MainTest().start();
    }

    public void start() throws InterruptedException {
        for (ConnectionInfo connectionInfo : HOSTS) {
            // Configure the client.
            EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
            try {
                Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
                b.group(group)
                        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                        .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                        .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                            @Override
                            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                                ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                                //p.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
                                p.addLast(new EchoClientHandler(buf.copy()));
                            }
                        });
                // Start the client.
                ChannelFuture f = b.connect(connectionInfo.getHost(), connectionInfo.getPort()).sync();
                // Wait until the connection is closed.
                f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
            } finally {
                // Shut down the event loop to terminate all threads.
                group.shutdownGracefully();
            }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectionInfo {
        private final String host;
        private final int port;

        public ConnectionInfo(String host, int port) {
            this.host = host;
            this.port = port;
        }

        public String getHost() {
            return host;
        }

        public int getPort() {
            return port;
        }
    }
}
```

and EchoClientHandler class:

```
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;

public class EchoClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private final ByteBuf message;

    public EchoClientHandler(ByteBuf buf) {
        message = buf;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(message);
        ctx.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

but if some server from the list is unavailable loop will be interrupted. I would like to fix this. Do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: To send one message to many devices at once, you should use multicast. The recipients should subscribe to a multicast group, and the sender just sends a message to the multicast group. This is precisely the problem for which multicast was designed as a solution.

Comment: @RonMaupin sure, but not for this case. it's just a test example for netty, nothing serious. But if you have some examples for using multicast in java, please share it with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 solutions:

1. wrap code in the loop to Thread class.
2. disable sync when connect to server

Let's consider these 2 solutions in the code.

**1. Wrap**:

```
for (ConnectionInfo connectionInfo : HOSTS) {
    new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // Configure the client.
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        // ....... etc
        } finally {
        // Shut down the event loop to terminate all threads.
        group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
    }.start();
}
```

**2. Disable sync**(and add some logging):

```
// Start the client.
ChannelFuture f = b.connect(connectionInfo.getHost(), connectionInfo.getPort());
f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
    if (future.isSuccess()) {
        // connection complete start to read first data
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Connected to {0}:{1} successfully.",
            new Object[]{connectionInfo.getHost(), connectionInfo.getPort().toString()});
    } else {
        // Close the connection if the connection attempt has failed.
        LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Connection problem to {0}:{1}.",
            new Object[]{connectionInfo.getHost(), connectionInfo.getPort().toString()});
    }
    }
});
// Wait until the connection is closed.
f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
```

Second solution looks more easy and I will prefer it.